# Soundmanager 2 wave form data

Tags: javascript, audio, waveform

I want to create and audio visualisation for audio on canvas and decided to use SoundManager2. The problem is function that should return waveformdata throws out empty arrays. Any idea what to do? (I hear the sound playing so it is loaded correct:) )

```
    <script>
    (function() {

     soundManager.url = 'swf/';
     soundManager.flashVersion = 9;

      soundManager.onready(function() {

       var i = 0;

var song = soundManager.createSound({
  id: 'song',
  url: 'https://www.mash-up.pl/sites/default/files/mp3/HF028A.mp3'
});

console.log(soundManager.features.waveformData); // true

function draw() {

  // emit waveform data every once in a while as to not break console
  if (!(i % 200)) {
    // wth these are empty
    console.log(song.waveformData.left);
    console.log(song.waveformData.right);
  }

  i++;
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(draw);

}

draw();

song.play();

     });

   })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok have found that soundobject has useWaveformData set to false (found it after debugging in console).

question can be closed :)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with the eqData in my html/js project, and I was wondering if you could take a look at my code as well (I tried adding the `useEQData: true` but with no effect): http://pastebin.com/WkzkECcS

Comment: @noahbkim same here. Did you find why is it empty?

Comment: Edit: I found that it has to use flash to show wave and eq data. ie `preferFlash: true`

Comment: @CihadTurhan, where do you put this? In `soundManager.setup(...)` or in `onready = function() {...}`